# Creating multiple forms based on stages of the workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

We have a workflow with multiple stages of approval. Till recently we have been using infopath. But now we had to use the default SharePoint list forms. I would need to create multiple forms or hide certain parts of a form based on the stages of the work flow.We use Microsoft flow to create workflow. is there any reference that i can take a look ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two generally easy ways you could do this.  One is that you could just use PowerApps and set rules for fields that toggle the visibility.  Here's a quick tutorial:

http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2017/11/16/how-to-hide-fields-in-sharepoint-list-forms-using-powerapps.aspx

The second way would to add a script editor webpart to your form pages and use javascript to show or hide fields based on approval status.  This way is a little more complex but still relatively straightforward:

http://mstechtalk.com/hide-fields-sharepoint-list-forms/

Comment: the first option seems good, can we hide or show fields based on the current user as well?. Since the list is in new view is it possible to use script editor in the modern view?

Comment: You can't add any JavaScript directly to modern SharePoint forms. The only option as of now to customize these forms is power-apps. Till I know in power app studio there is no option to add custom code.